# Datastore transaction does not lock

Tags: go, transactions, locking, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use Datastore as a distributed lock. Based on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#concurrency_modes), I'd expect the following to fail with `datastore: concurrent transaction`, but it only fails <5% of the time. The database used is in Optimistic concurrency mode.

How can I get it to lock on that entity and have any concurrent read/write operation fail?

This code is taken from the [official documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore@v1.14.0#Client.RunInTransaction), with the addition of a `Put` in between the transaction read and write.

```golang
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := datastore.NewClientWithDatabase(ctx, "project-id", "database-id")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    type Counter struct {
        Count int
    }

    var count int
    key := datastore.NameKey("Counter", "singleton", nil)
    if _, err = client.RunInTransaction(ctx, func(tx *datastore.Transaction) error {
        var x Counter
        if err := tx.Get(key, &x); err != nil && err != datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
            return err
        }

        y := x
        y.Count = 10
        if _, err = client.Put(ctx, key, &y); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        x.Count++
        if _, err = tx.Put(key, &x); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        count = x.Count
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = client.Delete(ctx, key); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("COUNT:", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure we're on the same page, is your database in `OPTIMISTIC` mode, or `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS`?

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#view_concurrency_mode

Assuming it is using `OPTIMISTIC` concurrency, starting the transaction and performing a read via `tx.Get(key, &x)` does not block another writer from modifying the same document. However the overall RunInTransaction operation should always fail assuming `client.Put(ctx, key, &y)` is a blocking operation that completes before the body of RunInTransaction finishes executing.

In `PESSIMISTIC` mode it *is* possible to use a write lock obtained in one transaction to delay other transactional writers from completing until the lock is released: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#concurrency_modes